# What exactly does the Standard tokenfilter do in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

[There are no examples in the documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/standard-tokenfilter/), and I was just wondering what to expect from input I give it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Before Elasticsearch 0.16 (Lucene 3.1) the standard token filter was "normalizing tokens extracted by standard tokenizer". To be specific, it was removing `'s` at the end of words and dots in acronyms. So, back then `Apple's` `C.E.O` would become `Apple` `CEO` after passing the standard filter. Starting with Elasticsearch 0.16 (Lucene 3.1) the standard token filter does [nothing](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/lucene_solr_4_3/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardFilter.java#L49) (at least at the moment). It simply passes tokens to the next filter in the chain.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an excerpt of the source code of StandardFilter from Lucene trunk.  It really does nothing.

```
public final boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {
    return input.incrementToken(); // TODO: add some niceties for the new grammar
}
```