# Elasticsearch standard tokenizer not handling "a.b" entries?

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize

I'm using ElasticSearch 0.90.7, so the answer to [What exactly does the Standard tokenfilter do in Elasticsearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928645/what-exactly-does-the-standard-tokenfilter-do-in-elasticsearch) I do not think applies (however what I'm seeing is similar).

I build the following:

```
curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/testindex"
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/testindex" -d'
{
  "mappings" : {
   "article" : {
     "properties" : {
       "text" : {
         "type" : "string"              
       }
     }
   }
 }
}'
```

I populate the following:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/testindex/article/1" -d'{
  "text": "file name. pdf"
}'

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/testindex/article/2" -d'{
  "text": "file name.pdf"
}'
```

Search returns the following:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/testindex/_search" -d '{
  "fields": [],
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "text",
      "query": "\"file name\""
    }
  }
}'

{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.30685282,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "testindex",
        "_type": "article",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.30685282
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

... given this, I'm guessing that the standard tokenizer is changing document #2 from **file name.pdf** into **file namepdf**

My questions are:

- am I guessing right here ?
- if so: any ideas what tokenizer I could use to handle these cases ? (Or will I need to process the texts in my client before submission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for yourself using the [Analyze API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html#indices-analyze).

This yields the tokens `file`, `name`, and `pdf` for `"file name .pdf"`,

and the tokens `file`, and `name.pdf` for `"file name.pdf"`.

The StandardAnalyzer, or rather the [StandardTokenizer](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/lucene_solr_4_6/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardTokenizer.java), implements the Word Break rules from the Unicode Text Segmentation algorithm, as specified in [Unicode Standard Annex #29](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/), which says:

> Do not break within sequences, such as “3.2”

So, `"name.pdf"` is considered a full word by the StandardTokenizer.

For your Query, the [SimpleAnalyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-simple-analyzer.html) would work. You can use the Analyze API as well as the [elasticsearch-inquisitor](https://github.com/polyfractal/elasticsearch-inquisitor) plugin to test the available analyzers.

Comment: Thanks for this - especially pointing out that there's an analysis tool for this aspect of the app. However I have a lot of docs that are both technical *and* japanese, which is a bugger, as simple will catch the case I mentioned above, but it doesn't handle asian passages well at all. And elasticsearch doesn't seem to allow multiple tokenizers. Ah well :-)

Comment: True, a document with mixed japanese and english is problematic.
Multiple tokenizers aren't allowed (on Lucene level), but I would try to use a multi_field (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-multi-field-type.html), using for example 'text.en' and 'text.jp' and set different analyzers for these fields.